# Listar diretório pela rede

Tags: php, arquivo, diretório

Estou usando o código abaixo para ler arquivos:
Localmente funciona, mas quando coloco a variavel $dir com um caminho de rede, conforme abaixo, recebo erro:

```
$dir = "W:/_Infraestrutura/Controles/Inventario de Equipamentos/ " ;   
$pasta= opendir($dir);    
echo "<ul data-role='listview' data-inset='false' data-filter='true'>";   
echo("<li data-role='list-divider'><a href='#'>A</a></li>"); 

while ($arquivo = readdir($pasta)){
    if ($arquivo != '.' && $arquivo != '..'){
        echo "<li><a href='".$dir.$arquivo."' rel='external' >".$arquivo."</a></li>";
        }
}
```

> Warning: opendir(W:/_Infraestrutura/Controles/Inventario de
>   Equipamentos/ ,W:/_Infraestrutura/Controles/Inventario de
>   Equipamentos/ ): in C:\wamp\www\termos\index.php on line 26
>
> Warning: opendir(W:/_Infraestrutura/Controles/Inventario de
>   Equipamentos/ ): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp\www\termos
>
> Warning: readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
>   in C:\wamp\www\termos\index.php on line 31\index.php on line 26

Comment: Tente passar o ip no lugar da unidade mapeada.

Comment: @rray ao passar o IP, o erro permanece

Comment: quando voce usa o `opendir()` o código procura pelo caminho dentro da propria pasta, tente subir alguns niveis para ver se funciona, use `.../`

Comment: @RafaelAcioly seria "../../../CAMINHO"?

Comment: Exatamente, faça um `var_dump($pasta)` ou `print_r($pasta)` e depois `die()` só para ver onde você esta e encontre e pasta onde quer chegar. ou use `getcwd ` para mostrar o nome do diretorio onde voce esta.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly mesmo erro =/

Comment: Você precisa especificar o protocolo, use `opendir("ftp://...")` ou `ftp_connect` Essa pergunta está respondida aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292984/php-opendir-on-another-server

Comment: Precisa ver se o usuário do Apache tem permissão pra acessar a rede

Comment: Em ambiente Windows é barra invertida. `W:\_Infraes....`

Comment: Para tirar dúvidas se o caminho está correto, pressione Windows+R. Copie o caminho na caixa de diálogo e dê um OK ou ENTER. Se não abrir, o caminho está errado.